# Array sorting ,not a simple sort

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, sorting

I have a long array,for the pagination!
I did a "premium" for the users. Now I want to sort array by the premium.
My array:

```
array:8 [▼
  0 => array:34 [▼
    "id" => 10
    "id_user" => "2"
    "vehicletype" => "car"
    "make" => "AMC"
    "model" => "Encore"
    "age" => "2017-01-14"
    "body" => "4"
    "price" => "94650"
    "vrt_price" => "102850"
    "vrt_date" => "2017-01-14"
    "condition" => "2"
    "mileage" => "12"
    "booth_space" => "1"
    "doors" => "1"
    "seat" => "14"
    "eng_size" => "1"
    "eng_hp" => "0.75"
    "eng_kw" => "1"
    "fuel" => "LPG"
    "trans" => "Semi-Au"
    "desc" => "133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333133333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333"
    "extras" => "2"
    "created_at" => "2017-01-14 14:13:00"
    "finish_at" => "2017-02-14 14:13:00"
    "updated_at" => null
    "premium_g1" => null
    "g1_start_at" => null
    "g1_finish_at" => null
    "premium_g2" => null
    "g2_start_at" => null
    "g2_finish_at" => null
    "extras_title" => array:1 [▶]
    "user_name" => "Szabolcs996"
    "images" => array:1 [▶]
  ]
  1 => array:34 [▶]
  2 => array:34 [▶]
  3 => array:34 [▶]
  4 => array:34 [▶]
  5 => array:34 [▶]
  6 => array:34 [▼
    "id" => 5
    "id_user" => "2"
    "vehicletype" => "car"
    "make" => "Aston Martin"
    "model" => "Rapide"
    "age" => "2017-01-14"
    "body" => "5"
    "price" => "4800"
    "vrt_price" => "1550"
    "vrt_date" => "2017-01-14"
    "condition" => "2"
    "mileage" => "450"
    "booth_space" => "1550"
    "doors" => "15"
    "seat" => "4"
    "eng_size" => "5"
    "eng_hp" => "79.5"
    "eng_kw" => "106"
    "fuel" => "LPG"
    "trans" => "Automatic"
    "desc" => "1234567891111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111115asssssssssssssssssssssss"
    "extras" => "2,4,7,8"
    "created_at" => "2017-01-14 12:43:19"
    "finish_at" => "2017-02-14 12:43:19"
    "updated_at" => "2017-01-22 17:04:08"
    "premium_g1" => "123"
    "g1_start_at" => "2017-01-23 09:45:58"
    "g1_finish_at" => "2017-02-04 09:45:58"
    "premium_g2" => "22"
    "g2_start_at" => "2017-01-23 09:45:58"
    "g2_finish_at" => "2017-02-22 09:45:58"
    "extras_title" => array:4 [▶]
    "user_name" => "Szabolcs996"
    "images" => array:12 [▶]
  ]
  7 => array:34 [▶]
]
```

So,that articles have `premium_g2` value! 
The important thing I not want to sort by MYSQL!

I have on every page 8 article.
I want to mix the articles,like on every page every second/third articles to be the premium.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use laravel collections.

```
collect($array)->sortBy('premium_g2');
```

You can also reverse the results.

```
collect($array)->sortByDesc('premium_g2');

collect($array)->sort('premium_g2')->reverse();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-sortby

To mix the articles I think the best solution might be to first group the data into two collections.

```
$collection = collect($array);
$total = $collection->count();
$sorted = $collection->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item['premium_g2'] === null ? 'standard' : 'premium';
}
```

This will give you a collection with two keys that you can access like so:

```
$sorted->premium
$sorted->standard
```

Then you can use the `$total` count to loop over and select which article to display. You can use the `shift()` method to pull out the first item from each collection so on the next loop it will select the next item.

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++)
    @if ($i % 3 === 0)
        {{ $sorted->premium->shift()['make'] }}
    @else
        {{ $sorted->standard->shift()['make'] }}
    @endif
@endfor
```

Comment: Thank you. It was helpful . I forgot to check the Laravel docs.. But to mix? :)

Comment: I've added a solution, sorry it took so long but I was trying to find a nice way of doing it and I'm at work. Let me know if there are any problems, I haven't tested but I think this should work.

Comment: Only one question. How can I stay on a same ->shift()['make'] ['model']['etc'] . Beacuse if I use always shift ,its moving for the next. :/